# Help with Python/GDAL documentation

Tags: python, gdal, wms, coordinate-system

The instructions from the url http://gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html give the following example:

`dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly)`

with the following description:

> It's interpretation is driver dependent, and it might be an URL...

I would like to know, what kind of URL is this? Where can I find a detailed description with  methods and attributes which illustrate how to use this function?

http://gdal.org/python/ does not help. I think, the only way I can understand this is to learn C++ and then to study GDAL source code, which is a very difficult way.

My goal is to convert a wms request (the request specifies the BBOX, HEIGHT, WIDTH, SRS=4326), storing the tile in memory on a server and reprojecting it using SRS=3857.

Comment: Everyone would like better documentation, but no-one is offering to write it. I think you are expected to know some GDAL concepts (maybe from the tutorial), and some python, and then to try it. There are some examples in the source code. Have you looked at those? Also http://geoinformaticstutorial.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/reading-raster-data-with-python-and-gdal.html might be useful. I think you should give it a try, then post a specific question rather than asking for a solution. There are higher-level alternatives, like owslib that might be better for your situation.

Comment: Thank u and i agree with u) I am from Russia we like word "Халява") I have not enough time but need quick result what`s why i need "Халява")

Comment: Check the format specific docs:

http://gdal.org/formats_list.html, or WMS specifically:

http://gdal.org/frmt_wms.html

Comment: @AlexanderKamenev I edited your question for clarity - can you check that I accurately described your goal at the end?

Comment: It's 2018 and the GDAL/OGR Python docs are still effectively useless. Sad to see such a powerful suite of tools be so out of reach because the maintainers haven't worked on the docs...